# Finding a singularity?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, singularity

This might be a silly question but why does $sin(z)/z$ have a singularity at $z=0$?

Because if you expand $sin(z)$ out you can get rid of the z term from the denominator.

Similarly, why does $sin(z)/z^3$ have pole or order 2 at z=0?!

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking the expression $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ does not have a value when $z=0$, because that would requite dividing by zero.

This missing point in the domain is the *only* missing point in a neighborhood of it, so *by definition* it is a singularity.

Your reasoning about the series expansion shows that it is a **removable** singularity, however.

Answer (score 0):

We have $\lim_{z \to 0} \sin(z)/z=1$, hence, by Riemann, the function $f(z)=\frac{\sin z}{z}$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$. Therefore the function $g$, defined by

$g(z)=f(z)$, if $z \ne 0$ and $g(0)=1$

is entire.

Since $\frac{\sin z}{z^3}=\frac{g(z)}{z^2}$ and $g(0) \ne 0$, $\frac{\sin z}{z^3}$ has a pole of order $2$ at $z=0$.

Comment: Ah thanks! In a more informal way, is it right in saying that sin(z)/z^3 has a pole of order 2 at z=0 because it would be order 3 (because of the z^3) but the sin(z) is also 0 so we just take 1 away? Hope that makes sense :/